# What are some great examples of on-topic questions for Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, scope

In light of the [discussion from earlier today](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64407/is-the-software-engineering-site-proposal-a-duplicate-of-programmers-se) about the difference between [Programmers.SE](http://programmers.stackexchange.com) and the [Software Engineering Area 51 proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/6922/software-engineering), I'd like to clarify what would be considered on-topic for Programmers.SE in its [FAQ proposal](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2/what-should-our-faq-contain).

I've [compiled a list of questions](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2/what-should-our-faq-contain/211#211) that would be considered great on-topic questions on Programmers.SE but off-topic on Stack Overflow. I'd also like to have a list of great on-topic questions on Stack Overflow, but would be considered off-topic on Programmers.SE.

I've tried doing searches for what's [hot or popular](https://stackoverflow.com/?tab=month), but of course, nearly all of the really popular questions are great examples of what would eventually be migrated to Programmers.SE should it get out of beta.

The following are three that I've come up with so far, but honestly, they are just random questions I picked from the sea of "hot" subjective or list-based questions:

- [Peak detection in a 2D array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3684484/peak-detection-in-a-2d-array)
- [Why doesn't jQuery bomb if your selector object is invalid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3709604/why-doesnt-jquery-bomb-if-your-selector-object-is-invalid)
- [Other ways to deal with “loop initialization” in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3596348/other-ways-to-deal-with-loop-initialization-in-c)

I'm interested to see if there are better, more clearer examples of what's quintessentially *Stack Overflow*. So what are some great Stack Overflow questions *sans* the subjective, popular ones that are the reason Programmers.SE was proposed?

---

#### Edit

I took the answers you guys provided below (thanks!), added an obligatory Code Golf question (because someone will ask), and here's the new list:

- [How do emulators work and how are they written?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448673/how-do-emulators-work-and-how-are-they-written)
- [round() for float in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/485525/round-for-float-in-c)
- [In-Place Radix Sort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/463105/in-place-radix-sort)
- [How to Round in MS Access, VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/137114/how-to-round-in-ms-access-vba)
- [Code Golf: Happy Primes!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3543811/code-golf-happy-primes)

Comment: Everything that's not closed, not cw and does have upvotes?

Comment: Code-golf has squeaked by on popularity, but the mere fact that there have been lengthy debates on meta makes it clear that it is *not* a great example. Likewise the fact that it is judged on an a different basis than the rest of the content on Stack Overflow. Sheesh.

Comment: This question is meant to flesh out how Stack Overflow is different than Programmers.SE, and in that context, I think it makes sense. Code Golf questions are not acceptable on Programmers.SE, but are acceptable on Stack Overflow, at least in practice. Whether that current practice on Stack Overflow is correct or up for debate is beyond the scope of Programmers.SE.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### One of my all-time favorites: [How do emulators work and how are they written?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448673/how-do-emulators-work-and-how-are-they-written)

It's a huge, broad question on a huge, broad topic... And the top answer is a shining example of how SO can work well: detailed, revised and expanded over time, plenty of links to specific information on various related topics and projects.

#### Another good one: [round() for float in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/485525/round-for-float-in-c)

Specific question on a specific need, complete with sample input & outputs, answers discussed in comments and revised in response... Note also the difference (both in score and content) between the "accepted" and top-ranked answers.

Comment: I like the first one as it's a great example of a question that doesn't involve any code yet is still categorically on-topic.

Answer (score 3):

One question that I remembered being asked by [Konrad Rudolph](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1968/konrad-rudolph) was [In-Place Radix Sort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/463105/in-place-radix-sort).  It's a particularly well thought out question.

Answer (score 1):

[Here's one on **Rounding in VBA**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/137114/how-to-round-in-ms-access-vba) with a lot of detailed answers that really cover the question.