# What happened to the Software Engineering proposal?

Tags: discussion, area-51

The proposal for a Software Engineering Stack Exchange site seems to have disappeared. Over the weekend, it achieved 100% commitment. However, I am no longer able to find this proposal. It has been removed from my user page. What happened?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently, due to some manner of conflict, the entire proposal has been redesigned. It has been renamed, reverted to the Definition Phase, and all example questions have been deleted. You can find it here: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/6922/software-engineering, where it has the following announcement at the top.

> NOTICE: To allieviate some of the confusion regarding this proposal, the "Software Engineering" proposal has been renamed and the definition clarified to reflect the author's original intent. The example questions have been removed but the list of followers has been retained.
>
> posted by Robert Cartaino♦ on Sep 20, 2010

I would guess that while followers have been retained, anyone who committed during the Commitment stage was dropped if they didn't follow during the Definition stage.

Comment: HA! That is... *Quite* the target audience...

Comment: This is essentially correct. The example questions did NOT reflect the proposal's original intent. Rather than folding it into Programmers.SE, the author and SO team decided that it would be better to clarify it as a site targeted more for the academic and professional "IEEE/ACM Engineering" crowd.

Comment: @Robert, why does the proposer's intent count for so much? I know I'd be pretty upset if people changed the direction of one of my proposals, but I thought the whole point of the definition process was for the community to decide what it wanted the site to be, not just feed a bunch of great example questions into someone's otherwise-fully-formed idea.

Comment: Ahh -- I see. It's about software engineering from an **academic** perspective. It's obvious now that it has nothing whatsoever to do with programming and shouldn't be folded in to anything. *ducks*

Comment: [Those interested should probably read this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64407/is-the-software-engineering-site-proposal-a-duplicate-of-programmers-se)... (get some popcorn first)

Comment: @Popular Demand: I'd agree with you except that would mean we simply close the proposal as a duplicate of Programmers.SE. The questions clearly belong there and the proposals developed in parallel. But the title/description wasn't sufficient to make the separation between Programmers.SE and the academic/professional target of software engineering sufficiently clear. And the underdeveloped communication facilities of Area 51 didn't allow for a course correction. So we worked to clarify the original intention of the proposal as best we could and said, essentially, to try again.

Comment: @Robert, okay. I don't know much about academic software engineering -- yet -- so I'll leave further discussion to others.

Comment: @Robert: I think it might be worth notifying (or auto following, or something) those users who committed during the commitment phase but hadn't followed. I was left wondering where the proposal had gone.